# How to use Authentication with CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Basically I have a controller/action - user/login (where a user logs in) and a controller images/add where a user can upload images.

I looked up http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html but I am a bit confused on how to do the following:

I want the user to be able to log in through user/login and be redirected to images/add (I want this page only be accessible if a user is logged in)

Right now I am not using Auth but instead I have this
UserController.php

```
   function login() 
    {   
        if(empty($this->data) == false) 
        {   
            if(($user = $this->User->validateLogin($this->data['User'])) == true) 
            {   
                $this->Session->write('User', $user); 
                $this->Session->setFlash('You\'ve successfully logged in.'); 
                $this->redirect('/images/add'); 
            }   
            else 
            {   
                $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, the information you\'ve entered is incorrect.'); 
            }   
        }   
    }
```

User.php model

```
function login() 
{   
    if(empty($this->data) == false) 
    {   
        if(($user = $this->User->validateLogin($this->data['User'])) == true) 
        {   
            $this->Session->write('User', $user); 
            $this->Session->setFlash('You\'ve successfully logged in.'); 
            $this->redirect('/images/add'); 
        }   
        else 
        {   
            $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, the information you\'ve entered is incorrect.'); 
        }   
    }   
}
```

How would I use the Authentication instead of Session based checking? Would I still have to use _validateLogin function in a model to check if the user in DB? Also how would I restrict images/add to be able to be accessible by logged in users?